# How do i get values of pin 4 to also get sent over to the slave and be displayed using I2C?

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

I am trying to get voltage values from my master to my slave but only the voltage from Pin3 is being sent over and not my values from pin 4. I am new to coding so please make your solution very "jargon-less." If you could provide me with an example then it will be greatly appreciated.

MASTER CODE:

```cpp
void pin3() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x08);
  int val2 = analogRead(twosensorpin);
  float volts2 = (val2 / 1023.0) * refvoltage;
  voltage = String(volts2);
  char volt2[5];
  voltage.toCharArray(volt2, 5);
  Serial.print("The voltage are pin 2 is ");
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Wire.write(volt2);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
  
void pin4() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x08);
  int val3 = analogRead(threesensorpin);
  float volts3 = (val3 / 1023.0) * refvoltage;
  voltage2 = String(volts3);
  char volt3[5];
  voltage.toCharArray(volt3, 5);
  Serial.print("The voltage are pin 3 is ");
  Serial.println(voltage2);
  Wire.write(volt3);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

SLAVE CODE:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0X08

String q;
String r = "3.20";

// name the motor control pins
#define PWMa 7
#define PWMb 5
#define PWMc 8
#define PWMd 6

void setup() {
  // configure the motor control pins as outputs
  pinMode(PWMa, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMb, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMc, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMd, OUTPUT);

  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  //Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {}
      
void receiveEvent() {
  q = "";

  while (Wire.available()) {
    char c = Wire.read();
    q += c;
  }
      
  do {
    if (q < r) {
      Serial.print("The value coming from pin 2 is ");
      Serial.println(q);
        
      digitalWrite(PWMa, LOW);
      digitalWrite(PWMb, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(PWMc, LOW);
      digitalWrite(PWMd, HIGH);
      //delay(500);
    }
  } while (Wire.available());

  do {
    if (q > r) {
      digitalWrite(PWMa, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(PWMb, LOW);
      digitalWrite(PWMc, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(PWMd, LOW);
    }
  } while (Wire.available());
```

Comment: It would be useful to show how your two MASTER functions are being called.  And the output of the SLAVE program.  But at first glimpse, I'd guess it's reading the first message (in the top loop) then getting stuck in one of the other loops.

Answer (score 1):

As Edd said you should show us some output.

But assuming you're trying to compare the incoming data to 3.20 **as a numerical value**, the following code will do the job.

**Master**

```
float send_i2c(int val){

  float volts = (val / 1023.0) * refvoltage;
  char v[5];
  String(volts).toCharArray(v, 5);
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x08);
  Wire.write(v);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  return volts;
}

void pin3(){
  Serial.println("Pin3 val : " + String(send_i2c(analogRead(twosensorpin))));
}


void pin4(){
  Serial.println("Pin4 val : " + String(send_i2c(analogRead(threesensorpin))));
}
```

**Slave**

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0X08
#define R 3.20

String q;

// name the motor control pins
#define PWMa 7
#define PWMb 5
#define PWMc 8
#define PWMd 6


void setup() {

  // configure the motor control pins as outputs
  pinMode(PWMa, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMb, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMc, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PWMd, OUTPUT);

  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {}

void receiveEvent(int a) {
  int num = 0;

  while (Wire.available())
    q += Wire.read();

  num = q.toInt();

  Serial.print("The value: ");
  Serial.println(q);

  digitalWrite(PWMa, (num < R) ? LOW : HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PWMb, (num < R) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(PWMc, (num < R) ? LOW : HIGH);
  digitalWrite(PWMd, (num < R) ? HIGH : LOW);

  q = "";

}
```

But again you should consider your way of controlling your GPIO outputs.

You've done quite a lot of mistakes. Check [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringComparisonOperators) to get more idea about Strings. And [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire) for Wire transmission.